# Unable to swap options in optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the dropdown
[image]

```
    <select id="officer-id" placeholder="Choose an officer">
              <option selected="selected" >----</option>
              <optgroup id="pt1" label="To be checked">
                <option value='ab2'>ab2</option>
                  --


              </optgroup>
              <optgroup id="pt2" label="Checked">
                 <option value='ab1'>ab1</option>

              </optgroup>

   </select>
```

What I want that on submit the selected item it optgroup pt1 should be removed and got added in optgroup pt2

I am trying something like this as i have to call this on sucess of submission

```
  $("#myform").submit(function(e){
    var officer_id = $('#officer-id').val();
    e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Home/insert_reviewofficer',
      //dataType:'json',
      data:$(this).serialize() + '&officer_id=' + officer_id,
      success:function(resp){
        // alert('success');
        // console.log(resp);
        $("#myform").hide();
          var value=$('#officer-id').val();
          $('#pt2').append($("#officer_id"));
      }
    });//end ajax
    });
```

But `$('#pt2').append($("#officer_id"))` is not adding and displaying  any option in optgroup #pt2

I want to implement this that **when I click submit** and on success of my ajax request the **optgroup TO be checked** should become **empty** and **optgroup checked** should **contain  options. ab1 and ab2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#pt2').append($("select").find(":selected"));
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v5q3oss/)